# How can I view the logs generated from the xcodebuild output?

Tags: ios, xcode, carthage

I am currently downloading dependencies via Carthage. When it comes to error, I need to see the log details.

```
xcodebuild output can be found in /var/folders/fj/1kwwbqhx5r3d0dp1g1fgjwbw0000gn/T/carthage-xcodebuild.dCp7BC.log
```

Would you please help me hot to redirect to the logs using Terminals and Finder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `open` like below. It will open the file with the default app of the extension.

```
open /var/folders/fj/1kwwbqhx5r3d0dp1g1fgjwbw0000gn/T/carthage-xcodebuild.dCp7BC.log
```

You can specify desired app with `-a`. For example below will open the file using `TextEdit`

```
open /var/folders/fj/1kwwbqhx5r3d0dp1g1fgjwbw0000gn/T/carthage-xcodebuild.dCp7BC.log -a TextEdit
```

Or you can just print it in the terminal using `cat`

```
cat /var/folders/fj/1kwwbqhx5r3d0dp1g1fgjwbw0000gn/T/carthage-xcodebuild.dCp7BC.log
```

Or you can just open the container folder in finder. Remember to delete the file name.

```
open /var/folders/fj/1kwwbqhx5r3d0dp1g1fgjwbw0000gn/T/
```